# Laravel - Eloquent Relationship not working in Mongo Using JsonArray

Tags: php, laravel

i am using mongoDB with Laravel. here is the Website document.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b68eeb2c2600fa0d42978fd"),
    "site_name" : "Agent Inc",
    "slug" : "agentinc",
    "wp_env" : "production",
    "wp_home" : "https://agentinc.co"
}
```

and here is the User document and i am using websites as Json Array in my User Document. like this.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c9e3ca99a8920189320ca62"),
    "name" : "Usman Fakhar",
    "website_ids" : [ 
        "5be9cc00cd14658a0554a05d", 
        "5c0ebcdbb149d84483aa305d", 
        "5c10f676b149d84483acaa33"
    ],
    "slug" : "usmanfc"
}
```

now in my User Model i am trying to use this relationship. but its not working.

```
public function websites(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Website', 'website_ids','_id');
}
```

this is returning an empty Collection when i try this.

```
$user->websites;
```

Answer (score 0):

hello guys i was watching Documentation and there was an excellent relationship called "embedsMany" for this. so this code Worked.

```
    return $this->embedsMany('App\Website', 'website_ids', '_id');
```